# random filenames on external hdd drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, malware

i am in big troubble. My friend gaves me his external usb hdd drive and told me, his files are deleted and renamed. 
I just want to restore the data with the program "recuva" but it dosn't work.

I don't know what it is. Is it Maleware? I just tried to search for maleware, but nothing was found. The HDD is in a good condition. Every Data has the same size. Its very strange.

Its a Western Digital HDD 150 GB

[image]

Comment: Its safe to say that the data is either corrupted, or encrypted based on the timestamps and filenames.  Based on that data recovery won't be possible.  As for it being malware that encrypted the files, if that's what happen, that's hard to say and we can't determine that from just the screnshot

Answer (score -1):

Try to use R-Studio, it saved me alot of time [R-Studio website](http://www.r-studio.com/) Install it and run from a separate disk drive! And - if USB-attached HDD is not repairing, don't give up - attach it directly and try again. This helps sometimes.

Comment: This is just another file recovery program.  What it can or cannot recover will likely be very similar to the program already used, the problem is the data appears to be encrypted, because all the files have the same modification date.  If `Recuva` can't recover it R-Studio won't be able to recover it.

Comment: recover the data and place it on a new HDD. If your friend used some h/w encryption - try to replace hdd with a new one, it can work out. I did it on my WD mybook one. If your h/w encryption module stores keys not in itself - refer to it's particular manual